# Why we use $ΔQ$ in thermodynamics if heat $Q$ is flow of energy? (What's difference are we calculating here?)

Tags: thermodynamics, notation

If I think heat as transfer of energy from hot body to cold body,  how I calculate difference  $\Delta Q$. Shouldn’t $Q$ be used instead?

Comment: What is the difference between $Q$ and $\Delta Q$ to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of $\Delta$ is generally restricted to mean the change in a thermodynamic property, such as temperature, pressure, internal energy, etc. But heat (and work) are not thermodynamic properties, since they are path dependent. To talk about a "change" in heat or a "change" in work makes no senses.

What does make sense is to talk about the "amount" of heat or work done between equilibrium states. Therefore, we usually refer to a small amount or work or heat as $\delta W$ or $\delta Q$, so called inexact differentials, to differentiate them from a small change in a property, i.e., $dU$.

So the differential expression of the first law is generally written as

$$dU=\delta Q-\delta W$$

For a finite change between equilibrium states it is written as

$$\Delta U=Q-W$$

where $Q$ and $W$ are understood to meant the "amount" of heat and work done between two equilibrium states, which are both path dependent,  and $\Delta U$ is understood to mean the change in internal energy between two states, which is not path dependent.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, *heat* is energy transfer on the microscopic level, unlike *work* which is the energy transfer due to the macroscopic changes. We consequently write the change in energy as
$$
\Delta U = Q - W,
$$
known as [the first law of thermodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_law_of_thermodynamics).

However, often we are dealing with a process, during which the energy transfer occurs by parts or continuously (e.g., in the parts of the process corresponding to different segments on a [PV diagram below](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure%E2%80%93volume_diagram)), and we are interested in the quantities associated with with each part. In this case it makes sense to use $\Delta$. Furthermore, since heat is not a real differential, it would be often written as $\delta$ or a crossed $d$:
$$
dU = \delta Q - PdV.
$$
[image]

Comment: Why heat is not a real differential?

Comment: @Himalayan neither heat nor work - because the same change in energy can be achieved via different paths (energy is a true differential)

Comment: "Firstly, heat is energy transfer on the microscopic level" I think we need to be careful here. At the microscopic level energy is transferred both from high to low and low to high temperature substances, depending on the energy levels of the specific molecules.  But at the macroscopic level it is only from high to low temperature as that represents the overall average energy transfer at the microscopic level.

Comment: @BobD microscopic/macroscopic here refers to the mechanism of transfer. Heat is transferred via collisions between molecules, without any macroscopic change of shape, which is what characterizes work.

Comment: I understand it is the mechanism of transfer. My point is it does not quantify the transfer. That only occurs at the macroscopic level. My comment was not intended as a criticism, just a cautionary point.  Some folks may not realize that energy transfer occurs both ways (hot-cold, cold-hot) at the microscopic level, but not at the macroscopic level where energy transfer only occurs hot to cold. And that is essential  to the definition of heat.

Comment: @BobD it was a useful comment, that *microscopic* may mean different things here.